# Saved database values doesn't show on front end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to call these default values to my header file, which I can successfully do but problem is these option stays and doesn't get overridden by database values, which it should. Even if I change layouts from the customizer(which ultimately saves to database). These defaults values show up meaning my saved database option doesn't show on front end.

For example - "frontpage_layouts" has "layout_3" set to default, But If I change the layout to some other options like "layout_1" via customizer. Layout_1 should show but layout_3 always shows on the front end. I don't know why it happening.

```
<?php function tar_option_defaults() {

//default values
$defaults = array(
    'frontpage_order_setting' => 'cta,features,text-section,porfolio,testimonial,blog,clients,sec-cta',
    'frontpage_layouts' => 'layout_3',
    'txt_section_layout' => 'layout_2',
    'testi_layout' => 'layout_3',
    'feature_block_layouts' => 'layout_3',
    'portfolio_section_layout' => 'layout_1',
    '2nd_cta_layout' => 'layout_3',
    'blog_layout' => 'layout_3'
);

  $options = get_option('tar',$defaults);

  //Parse defaults again - see comments
  $options = wp_parse_args( $options, $defaults );

return $options; }
```

Here's the code I'm calling the layouts from -

```
 if ( get_option( 'tar[frontpage_layouts]' ) === 'layout_1' ) { 

        get_template_part( 'frontpage/content', 'cta1' ); }

if ( get_option( 'tar[frontpage_layouts]') === 'layout_2' ) { 

        get_template_part( 'frontpage/content', 'cta2' ); }

if ( get_option( 'tar[frontpage_layouts]' ) === 'layout_3' ) { 

        get_template_part( 'frontpage/content', 'cta3' ); }  ?>
```

May be it's something to do with "wp_parse_args" tag ? I don't know. Can anybody chime in and help me out ?

Comment: The customizer settings are saved in `theme_mods_{yourt heme name}` option name in the options tables. And you are pulling the options from `tar` option name. Those are not the same things...

Comment: I know theme_mods_themename saves options in a serialize way in database. I'm not using theme_mods_tar  I'm using "option" here

Comment: Yeah but you said that if you overwrite the options in the customizer nothing happens...